# Using Visualization Toolkit with IronPython

Tags: c#, ironpython

In my application, I have provision to run Python scripts through IronPython. In one of the requirement, the data from my C# application should be displayed in 3D using Visualization Toolkit. When I try to use VTK in a script and execute it, I get "ImportError: No module named vtk" error. I have searched for file named `vtkCommonPython.pyd` but cannot find it on my computer. Should Python be installed even after installing IronPython? What is the correct way to use VTK from IronPython?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, IronPython does not work with native/CPython modules like what `vtkCommonPython.pyd` seems to be. You will probably want to look at .NET bindings for VTK in order to use it from your IronPython scripts.

ActiViz.NET might be what you should be using. [Wiki/Documentation](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/CSharp/ActiViz.NET), [Download](http://www.kitware.com/opensource/avdownload.php)

Other modules containing only pure python should typically work fine. It's 'just' the native extensions that do not work as there is no easy (and built-in) way to make native code callable from .NET/IronPython using the same conventions as in CPython.

For additional info see [the FAQ ('Compatibility')](https://ironpython.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ) and the [issue tracker](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/issues/296).

You might also want to keep an eye on the [recent effort](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironclad) to revive and port [ironclad](https://code.google.com/p/ironclad/) to IronPython 2.7. This project aims to provide the marshalling layer required to invoke CPython modules.

Comment: Is it not possible to add modules to IronPython? Using DistUtils? I dont know python..Sorry if you find the question lame..:)

Comment: I added additional info that should answer your comment/questions.